# Docusign - How to disable the navigation tab in the left?

Tags: docusignapi

When users open the document to sign, on the left of the document, there is a yellow tab 'next'. How to disable that? Or at least change the color. We are using embedded signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable the "Next" button, it's a part of the UX. You can probably change its color, see the [Branding Guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding).